# What's the difference when I create Code First relation setting only a collection

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am using `Entity Framework 5` with Code First. I update my model(entities) while I'm writing the business logic which leads to some problems. Since now when I wanted to create `1 : N` relationship I was using this approach:

```
Entity-1
{
  public int Entity-1ID { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Entity-N> Entity-Ns { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
Entity-N
{
  public int Entity-NID { get; set; }
  public int Entity-1ID { get; set; }
  public virtual Entity-1 Entity-1 { get; set; }
}
```

bur recently I faced the problem with the need of null Foreign Keys (I needed to add more relations to some entities) and since I am already using GenericRepository where all types are value types (no nullables) and also have some code written based on that I decided that it's too late to change all this.

Since I already have Foreign Key for some entity and I need to relate that entity with a new one I have faced a problem.

My solution is - when I have a new entity I only add collection from the existing entity to the new one (or vice-verca). What bothers me is - what kind of problems this may cause if I use it.

Right now I have entity `Page` where

```
Page
{
  public virtual ICollection<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }
}
```

and as expected in `SomeEntity` I don't have a `FK` for `Page` but when I look at the `Microsoft SQL Management Studio` I see that the `SomeEntities` table has a column called `Page_PageID`.

Can someone explain me what exactly happens when I make a relation like this. Why even though I have this column `Page_PageID` which practically acts as `FK` I can't use it from my code and why if I explicitly define `public int PageID { get; set; }` in `SomeEntitiy` and I try to change `int` to `int?` I get all kinds of errors for trying to use null but with this auto-created column `Page_PageID` there's no problem to have records with null values for it.

Comment: I recommend reading about code first conventions, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question:Can someone explain me what exactly happens when I make a relation like this?

```
Page
{
  public virtual ICollection<SomeEntity> SomeEntities { get; set; }
}
```

In Code First,if there is a collection property between two entities,Entity Framework will create a one-to-many relationship.That means the entity has collection property is the principal end of the relationship,the other entity is the dependent end.And,in the table of the dependent entity,Entity Framework will generate a foreign key to the principal table.
So,The collection property "SomeEntities" of entity Page will cause the Entity Framework to generate a foreign key in the table of entity "SomeEntity".

There are three scenarios that Code Frist will treat as a one-to-manay relationship between to entities.
1.There is a reference navigation property in one entity.
2.There is a collection navigation property in one entity(Your Page entity belong to this).
3.There is a reference navigation property in one entity,and a collection navigation property in the other entity.

Your question:Why even though I have this column Page_PageID which practically acts as FK I can't use it from my code .

If you want to use the foreign key,you should define a foreign key property in entity "SomeEntity".By default,Entity Framework generate a foreign key with the below patterns:
[Target Type Key Name],[Target Type Name] + [Target Type Key Name],or [Navigation Property Name] + [Target Type Key Name].that is why your foreign key named "Page_PageID".You can use the annotation "ForeignKey".

Your question: why if I explicitly define public int PageID { get; set; } in SomeEntitiy and I try to change int to int? I get all kinds of errors for trying to use null but with this auto-created column Page_PageID there's no problem to have records with null values for it..

<s>By default,if the primary key is value types,the foreign key to it will be not null.And that means the relationship is required.
I can not see the key of your Page entity.If it's type is int,the auto-created column Page_PageId(foreign key to Page) will be not null too.</s>Did you show your whole Page entity?

If you did not define a foreign key(like public int PageId) in SomeEntity,code first will generate a foreign key named with pattern [Target Type Name]_[Target Type Key Name],that is Page_PageId.And in this case(there is no foreign key property in the dependent entity),the foreign key generated by Entity Framework in silence  will be null.
But if you explicitly define a foreign key property,like public int PageId,the nullability of the foreign key in the database will be determined by the type of the foreign key property(value types is not null).
So,like your question,when you with the auto-created FK column Page_PageID,the FK is null,you can insert leave it null.When you explicitly defined a foreign key property,public int PageID { get; set; },the FK PageId will be not null,because PageId is integer.
Some more,you can control the nullability of FK int the database by specifying the PageId as int?.Again,**By convention, Code First is using the nullability of the foreign key
property in your class to determine if the relationship is required or optional.**

Comment: About my Entity `Page` - no, it has a lot more properties but it's primary key is explicitly defined - `public int PageID { get; set; }`.